# How to count the amount of unique lines, duplicate lines and lines that appear three times in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, uniq

I have a list of names, one name per line saved as a .txt file.

I'm trying to use bash to determine how many different names appear once, two times or three times.

For example:

names.txt looks like

```
Donald
Donald
Lisa
John
Lisa
Donald
```

In this case the amount of unique lines is 1, there's 1 duplicate and 1 name appears 3 times. I'm trying to get these amounts on a bigger list with using `uniq`. I know that I can use `uniq -u` and `uniq -d` for uniques and duplicates but I'm not quite sure how to do it with names that appear 3 times.

Comment: This is very broad. What should the output look like? Have you actually tried using `uniq`? It won't work on its own, and I don't think you can use it directly to find words appearing three times. (What about words appearing more than three times?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo 'Donald
Donald
Lisa
John
Lisa
Donald' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
   1 1
   1 2
   1 3
```

The right column is the repetition count, and the left column is the number of unique names with that repetition count. E.g. “Donald” has a repetition count of 3.

Bigger example:

```
echo 'Donald
Donald
Rob
Lisa
WhatAmIDoing
John
Obama
Obama
Lisa
Washington
Donald' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
   4 1
   2 2
   1 3
```

Four names (“Rob”, “WhatAmIDoing”, “John”, and “Washington”) each have a repetition count of 1. Two names (“Lisa” and “Obama”) each have a repetition count of 2. One name (“Donald”) has a repetition count of 3.

Comment: I was just going to post exactly this with my convoluted awk answer below.  Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting to show something like this?

```
3 Donald
2 Lisa
1 John
```

If yes, then this following should do:

```
cat <file> | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Comment: If someone is expecting this kind of output and looking to explore further:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622855/print-count-number-of-unique-pattern-occurences-after-each-occurence

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the actual names for each "repetition count", perl is a good choice with its very flexible data structures:

```
perl -lne '
    $count{$_}++;
    END {
        while (($name, $num) = each %count) {
            push @{$map{$num}}, $name;
        }
        while (($num, $names) = each %map) {
            print "$num: @$names";
        }
    }
' << NAMES
Donald
Donald
Lisa
John
Lisa
Jim
Bob
Jim
Donald
NAMES
```

```
3: Donald
1: John Bob
2: Jim Lisa
```

Comment: You omitted "Hillary" ;-)

Comment: No, that's just Donald, not "The Donald". Woo, political satire on SO: edgy!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a distinct count of names by using arrays in `awk`:

```
awk '{ a[$1]++ } END { for (n in a) print n, a[n] } ' yourfile
```

I suppose, if you wanted to go one step further, you could run the same awk script against the output of this one, but on $2, to get the count of counts, which sort of sounds like what you are after. Sort of like:

```
awk '{ a[$1]++ } END { for (n in a) print n, a[n] } ' test |  awk '{ a[$2]++ } END { for (n in a) print n, a[n] } '
```

Which will output:

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
```

Which is saying "There are 1 distinct names that show up once. There are 1 distinct names that show up 2 times. There are one distinct names that show up 3 times"

I'm certain that could be done in a single awk script, but this seems simple enough as it is and it's pretty easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END{for(k in a) b[a[k]]++; for(k in b) print b[k], k}' names
```

Comment: more descriptive variable names would help.